# debian 11 Notepad ++ not running after snap install

Tags: debian, software-installation, snap

I am new to linux so I am sorry if this is an easy question.

I followed https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-notepad-on-linux however when I go search the applications folder for notepad++ it does not exist. I also tried running notepad-plus-plus and I get this error.

```
root@lintro:~# notepad-plus-plus
-bash: notepad-plus-plus: command not found
```

I then tried this as I believed I could just run it from snap

```
root@lintro:~# sudo snap run notepad-plus-plus
cannot load program:

: Invalid argument
```

I will add edits as I dont know what to look for or what else I need to show.

I have followed the tips on notepad-plus-plus snap does not start on Ubuntu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923102/notepad-plus-plus-snap-does-not-start-on-ubuntu

I am on Debian GNU/linux version 11

Comment: just to verify: just installing `wine` (`sudo apt install wine`) and running "portable" Notepad++ doesn't work either, right?

Comment: How do I run portable notepad++?

Comment: you install wine, you get the zip, unpack it, double click the .exe (or right click-> open with wine). Or you unpack, open a terminal, `cd` to the directory where you've unpacked it, and run `wine notepad++.exe`.

Comment: I got other errors I will work through them and then report back. Looks promising though

Comment: That worked. Can you please make an answer so I can confirm it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snap` can be really useful when you're installing complex software. Notepad++ isn't that complex, and supported by wine out of the box. Just install wine (`sudo apt install wine`), download the notepad++ portable, unpack it, and run it with wine.

I haven't tried it, but if you run the official installer instead of unpacking the portable version, you'd probably even get file associations in your file manager, so that double clicking source code files can open them in notepad++.

Also note that while I think it's good to use an editor you're used to, there's very similar editors to notepad++ for Linux that you can trivially install directly: `geany` even uses the same editor component as notepad++! You can install it using `sudo apt install geany geany-plugins-common`. `scite` also uses the same code editor, and is as minimal as notepad++ (`sudo apt install scite`). There's also really a wealth of other, easy to install-and-use code editors. Some of my friends swear on `kate` (`sudo apt install kate`), others love vscodium, some code::blocks, other spyder, others are vim or emacs or spacemacs users.